# Translate Go Regexp to Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, go

How would this Go Regexp translate to JavaScript?

```
"[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[\\w](?:[\\w-]*[\\w])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[\\w-]*[\\w])?"
```

Comment: by copy/pasting into a .js file?

Comment: @rikkigibson is right, that is a monstrosity of a pattern.  Better to match 99% of cases with a clear & succinct regular expression rather than wading through a pile of ascii puke that *ehem* _still_ only catches 99% of cases.

Btw, fantastic presentation about ascii puke here: [/Reg(exp){2}lained/: Demystifying Regular Expressions](https://youtu.be/EkluES9Rvak)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There has to be a better way to do what you're doing than that monstrosity of a pattern.
2. Regular expressions tend to be pretty portable. You should just drop it into a regex tester (Google it) or a script file and see if you get the matches you expect. If you don't, rebuild the regex in chunks and see which piece causes it to fail.

Comment: Believe me, I know it is a monster. I ended up pretty much doing what you have suggested for #2 and accepted your answer. Interesting how much the syntax between Go and Javascript differs for Regexp.